# PrintManager Context

Tags: android

This may be a dopey question, but here goes:

I am attempting to use PrintManager to generate a printed report. The documentation indicates that to get a handle you use

```
PrintManager printManager =
     (PrintManager) context.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

In other docos they use

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
```

Eclipse spits the dummy telling me that "The method getActivity() is undefined for the type PrintActivity (my Activity)"

My imports include

```
import android.print.PrintAttributes;
import android.print.PrintDocumentAdapter;
import android.print.PrintJob;
import android.print.PrintManager;
```

I tried replacing getActivity() with "this" and it compiles however the Emulator tells me that 
" Could not find class 'android.print.PrintManager', referenced from method com.kitstop.score.PrintActivity.createWebPrintJob

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're correct in using `this` in the `Activity`. `getActivity()` is a method of the `Fragment` class. As far as the class not found error, printing in Android wasn't introduced until API Level 19 (KitKat), so if you're not running in that version or above, you'll get that error. Check that your `targetSdkVersion` is correct.

Comment: The app is set up for api 19 but the emulator was only at 15. Would this be the problem? I have been unable to get the emulator to load with 19.

Comment: That sounds like the problem. I wish I could give you some pointers to fix it, but I don't use Eclipse.

Comment: can you show us full code...?